# How can I delete my texts?

Tags: sms

I did not realize if you have more than about 400 SMS texts in one stack, the phone seems unable to delete. I have over 5000 SMS texts in one stack and I don't have the time or patience to delete them all individually.

Hope someone can help

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All` and clear the data for **Messaging Storage** or something similar, depending on your particular device and software.

Answer (score 2):

This app should allow you to do it per contact. https://market.android.com/details?id=cn.com.opda.android.clearmaster

Comment: Great thank's a lot! It allowed me to delete the messages of only the contacts I wanted. This app in fact doesn't seem to work a lot faster than deleting with the native Android sms app, but at least it shows a descriptive progress bar with a percentage. But be prepared, the translation is really bad.

Comment: It appears that the app is not available in Play Store anymore. Would you care for an edit to mention that this answer wouldn't work anymore and is here for historical reason? Alternatively, could you add an alternative to that app in your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there.  No idea if it will work, because I don't have any text threads with that many to test it on, but have you tried doing it in some *other* text message clients?  Which one are you using now?  Try it in the default text client, and then try downloading [Handcent SMS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/handcent-sms/com.handcent.nextsms) or [Chomp SMS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/chompsms/com.p1.chompsms) and see if you can do it from there.  Sometimes different apps will make it possible to do something that another app that's *supposed* to be able to accomplish, cannot.

Good luck!